# continuously loading if there is no internet connection

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am currently developing a Online Controlled home but I have a problem with the internet connection checker.

I have this code to detect whether there is an internet connection or there is no internet connection.

```
$check = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80); 
if($check){
    return true;
    fclose($check);
}else{
     return false;
     fclose($check);
}
```

but the problem is, when my Raspberry Pi don't have an internet connection then it continuously load the page forever.

the full script is here

```
<?php
    function checkConnection(){
        $check = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80); 
        if($check){
            return true;
            fclose($check);
        }else{
             return false;
             fclose($check);
        }
    }
    if(checkConnection()==true){
        echo '[{"status":"success","result":"Internet Connection is Available"}]';
    }else{
        echo '[{"status":"fail","result":"No Internet Connection"}]';
    }
?>
```

Comment: close the socket connection only when success connection

Comment: use `json_encode` to echo your response, like, `echo json_encode(["status" => "success","result" => "Internet Connection is Available"]);`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestion but still the same result :(

Comment: Your function will not work as DNS will not resolve the hostname when internet connection is not there.? Try with IP & also set a timeout at end. Also do check that whrther google allows port 80 connection!!

Comment: actually my advice was not about the question :) just a tip, well as @CoderSam said, dns will try to resolve the google.com domain which will take a long time before it times out, consider adding the timeout param to your `fsockopen(..., $timeout);`

Comment: @xanadev I tried but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a small change in your function might enlighten the situation. For example:

```
   function checkConnection() {
         $fp = @fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 3); 
         if (!$fp) {
             return "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
         } else {
             return true;
         }
    }
    $con = checkConnection();
    if ($con===true) {
        echo json_encode( ["status" => "success","result" => "Internet Connection is Available"] );
    } else {
        //  should not be - No Internet Connection is Available
        echo json_encode( ["status" => "fail","result" => $con] );
    }
```

> PS: Try it out in [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and make sure to change the port from `80` to `83` for example. This of course does not mean that you don't have internet connection but that the host you reach at the specified port does not reply. Anyway it will simply fail the function and return the error message. Also please do notice the `timeout` limit of 3 seconds in `fsocopen` since you may alter it accordingly to your needs.

**EDIT**

A simpler and perhaps more accurate approach on what you are trying to do could be this.

```
   function checkConnection($hostname) {           
         $fp = gethostbyname($hostname);
         if (!inet_pton($fp)) {
            return json_encode( ["status" => "fail","result" => "Internet Connection is not Available or Host {$hostname} is wrong or does not exist."] ); 
         } else {
            return json_encode( ["status" => "success","result" => "Internet Connection is Available. Host {$hostname} exists and resolves to {$fp}"] );
         }
    }
    echo checkConnection('www.google.com');
```

> You might want to check this [comment in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php#118841) on setting alternative options for `gethostbyname`.

Comment: still it keeps loading. unending load

Comment: @MarverickM. based on the code snippet presented in this question and the tests done in PHPFiddle you should get an error. Please post any other relevant code that may help this question.

Comment: @MarverickM. In addition you may want to alter a bit this example function to provide an error when DNS lookup fails https://www.askapache.com/php/php-fsockopen-dns-udp/

Answer (score 0):

[fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) takes a timeout as the last param, which only applies while connection the socket

DNS lookup can be a factor too, AFAIK you can't control the timeout for that, unless if you're going to use `gethostbyname()` in that case you can use

`putenv('RES_OPTIONS=retrans:1 retry:1 timeout:1 attempts:1');`

to limit DNS lookup to **1s**.

Based on your code here's how i would implement it.

```
function is_connected()
{
    //1. provide a timeout to your socket
    //2. use example.com as a domain, that's what it's made for (testing)
    $socket = @fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $err_no, $err_str, 5);
    if ($socket){
        fclose($socket);
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}

$success = json_encode(["status" => "success","result" => "Internet is Available"]);
$failure = json_encode(["status" => "fail","result" => "Internet is Unavailable"]);

echo is_connected() ? $success : $failure;
```